# String to dictionary from a different file

Tags: python

I have a database full of those strings:

```
'"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[4.916520921976682,43.58795128864228],[4.916519615794914,43.58792348750154],[4.916427403085649,43.58792577651196],[4.916428709224705,43.58795357765377],[4.916520921976682,43.58795128864228]]]},"properties":{"color":"blue","shapeRepresents":"string","name":"G11.01/2"},"id":"1823481"'
```

and I need to read them as a python dictionary. I tried eval() but it says invalid syntax. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

this is malformed JSON. Enclose in curly brackets and use `json` module to parse it.

```
spam = '"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[4.916520921976682,43.58795128864228],[4.916519615794914,43.58792348750154],[4.916427403085649,43.58792577651196],[4.916428709224705,43.58795357765377],[4.916520921976682,43.58795128864228]]]},"properties":{"color":"blue","shapeRepresents":"string","name":"G11.01/2"},"id":"1823481"'
import json
from pprint import pprint
eggs = json.loads(f'{{{spam}}}')
pprint(eggs)
```

output

```
{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[[4.916520921976682, 43.58795128864228],
                               [4.916519615794914, 43.58792348750154],
                               [4.916427403085649, 43.58792577651196],
                               [4.916428709224705, 43.58795357765377],
                               [4.916520921976682, 43.58795128864228]]],
              'type': 'Polygon'},
 'id': '1823481',
 'properties': {'color': 'blue',
                'name': 'G11.01/2',
                'shapeRepresents': 'string'},
 'type': 'Feature'}
```

Note, after adding curly brackets you can use `ast.literal_eval()` instead of `json.loads()`. Your `eval()` will also work, but it is discouraged.